# Empty String in a column in sql server 2019- with Varying string length

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the column of table contains Some NULL and Some Empty String. `''`

Query I have written to filter those NULL and Empty string like.

```
SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TABLE WHERE COLB IS NOT NULL OR COLB !=''
```

Now the issue is empty string is looks like.

```
 ''
' '
'   '
'       '...... etc --- This is just example sample.
```

Is there any way to handle such scenario.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `IS NULL` check, you don't need it and it's causing your results to be wrong.

When comparing a string, a (not) equal operator already implicity removes `NULL` values as `NULL != <something>` returns UNKNOWN, which isn't TRUE. As you are checking the value isn't `NULL` or not equal to `''` you effectively get any rows that don't have the value `NULL` as `''` *isn't* `NULL`.

There's no need to also check if the string is only filled with whitespace, as trailing spaces are "trimmed" for comparison reasons. this means that `''` and `'      '` are considered equal, and so `'' != '        '` would result in FALSE:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(''),
            ('    '),
            (NULL),
            (' '),
            ('a'))V(YourColumn)
WHERE YourColumn != '';
```

| YourColumn |
| --- |
| a |